# How to run second view controller only when data from server is loaded in coredata from first view controller in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my app when login is completed in same VC data is loaded from server in coredata, but delay in loading the data from server to coredata in next table view of second VC have empty list. So, i want to run second vc only after loading the data in coredata from first VC.

```
for teEmp in json {

                    if teEmp.valueForKey("department") !== null {
                        if teEmp.valueForKey("department")  as! String == "Technology"{

                            // start core data

                            let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Tech", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectcontext!)
                            let tech = Employees(entity: entityDescription!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectcontext)

                            tech.id = teEmp.valueForKey("id")! as? String
                            tech.first_name = teEmp.valueForKey("firstname")! as? String
                            tech.card_id = (teEmp.valueForKey("cardId")!) as? String
                            tech.image = (teEmp.valueForKey("image")!) as? String
                            tech.last_name = (teEmp.valueForKey("lastname")!) as? String
                            tech.designation = (teEmp.valueForKey("designation")!) as? String
                            tech.department = (teEmp.valueForKey("department")!) as? String
                            if teEmp.valueForKey("startedDate") as! String != "null" {
                                let dateAsString = teEmp.valueForKey("startedDate")
                                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/YYYY"
                                let teStartDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString((dateAsString as? String)!)
                                dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
                                //dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd YYYY"
                                let techStartDay = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(teStartDate!)
                                tech.started_date = techStartDay as String
                            }
                            tech.departure_date = (teEmp.valueForKey("departureDate")!) as? String
                            tech.responsibilities = (teEmp.valueForKey("responsibilities")!) as? String
                            tech.address = (teEmp.valueForKey("address")!) as? String
                            tech.email = (teEmp.valueForKey("email")!) as? String
                            tech.shift = (teEmp.valueForKey("shift")!) as? String
                            tech.linkedIn_profile = (teEmp.valueForKey("linkedInProfile")!) as? String
                            tech.new_employee = (teEmp.valueForKey("newEmployee")!) as? String
                            tech.departed = (teEmp.valueForKey("departed")!) as? String
                            tech.supervisor = (teEmp.valueForKey("supervisor")!) as? String

                            if teEmp.valueForKey("birthDate") as! String != "null" {
                                let dateAsString = teEmp.valueForKey("birthDate")
                                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd"
                                let teBirthDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateAsString as! String)
                                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
                                let techBirthMonth = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(teBirthDate!)
                                tech.birth_date = techBirthMonth
                            }

                            tech.privacy = (teEmp.valueForKey("privacy")!) as? String
                            if (teEmp.valueForKey("privacy")!) as? String == "PUBLIC"{
                                tech.contact = (teEmp.valueForKey("contact")!) as? String
                            } else {
                                tech.contact = "98********"
                            }



                            do {
                                try self.managedObjectcontext!.save()
                                print("Tech data saved in core data")

                            } catch let error as NSError
                            {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)


                            }
                            // end core data

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }catch  let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }

        if(err != nil) {
            print(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")

        }
        else {


        }
```

Comment: try NSNotificationCenter or delegate methods

Comment: Please show us the code that you have try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSNotificationCenter/ Delegation Pattern/ Passing a closure/ ReactiveCocoa to achieve this. 
Here is an example using NSNotificationCenter.

```
do {
     try self.managedObjectcontext!.save()
     print("Tech data saved in core data")
     // Add this line
     let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
     notificationCenter.postNotificationName("CoreDataSaved", object: nil)
}
```

Then move to your FirstViewController:
In viewdidload method, add following-

```
let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                   selector: "ShowSecondVC",
                   name:"CoreDataSaved",
                   object: nil
                    )
```

and add the function to push your second view controller.

```
func ShowSecondVC() {
  // Show second VC
}
```

Finally, remove the notification listener from First VC in deinit block.

```
deinit {
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```